# in Python, how do you slice with a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, slice

```
mystring = '[:3]'
x = mystring.split()
z = str(x).lstrip("['").rstrip("]'")
print(z)
print('hello'+int(z))
```

error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ':3'

How can I make the output 'hel' by slicing with the 'mystring' variable?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: slice the word 'hello' with 'mystring' so the output would be 'hel'

Comment: Don't use a string. Use a `slice` object. Or just slice notation. Otherwise, you'll have to parse the string some how to extract the items you'd pass to the slice object or use with slice notation anyway.

Comment: unfortunately it's a user input

Comment: Ok, then parse the string. What is the source of this user input? Why does it look like this: `[:3]`??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exec` function. The `exec()` method executes the dynamically created program, which is either a string or a code object.

```
>>> mystring = '[:3]'
>>> exec('print("hello"{})'.format(mystring))
hel
```

If you want to take Python code from the user

```
>>> program = input('Enter a program:')
Enter a program:print("hello"[:3])
>>> exec(program)
hel
```

**Be careful while using exec()** Read the documentation carefully before using it.